# A practical example of uniform convergence of a hypothesis class

Tags: convergence

From definition of uniform convergence:

> We say that a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ has the uniform convergence property (w.r.t. a domain Z and a loss function $l$) if there exists a function $m_{H}^{UC} : (0,1)^{2} \rightarrow N$ such that for every $\epsilon, \delta \in (0,1)$ and for every probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $Z$, if $S$ is a sample of $m ≥ m_{H}^{UC}(\epsilon,\delta)$ examples drawn i.i.d. according to $D$, then, with probability of at least $1 − \epsilon$, $S$ is $\epsilon$-representative.

I'm wondering if there's some concrete example of uniform convergence $\mathcal{H}$ that illustrates this definition?